# Cursor inside trigger and updating the table column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables

one is userDetails with columns User_Id,User_name,Name and lastModifiedDate.
Second is Role with columns roleId,RoleName and
third table is User_Role with columns user_Id(foreign key referencing UserDetails) and Role_id (foreign key referencing Role).

Now the thing is whenever any update or delete operation happens in Role table I need to update the column lastModifiedDate of UserDetails table by getting the respective mapped user_Id from User_Role table.

For example, I have roleId as 1,2,3,4 in Role table and roleId '3' is mapped with user_Id 101,102,103,104 in User_Role table. So if roleId '3' is updated in Role table then I need to get those mapped userId from User_Role and update their lastModifieddate column with sysdate.

I have to use trigger, but how I don't know as I am a newbie in DB and have no knowledge on it...please help guys
And I have to do it in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create trigger like this:

```
 create or replace trigger PT_AD_ROLE after DELETE OR UPDATE on ROLE_TABLE for each row
      begin

       update user_table set lastModifiedTime=current_timestamp() from user_table u,role_table r,user_role  ur where r.role_id=ur.role_id and ur.user_id=u.user_id and r.role_id=:old.role_id;
    end

;
```

Comment: Whenever u make change to role table, the :old.user_id will have the user_id which you did changes. Then use this value to make changes to the user_table.

Comment: my role table doesn't have any userId column...it is mapped in user_role table..
There are three tables

Answer (score 0):

No worries we are all new once, and sql is a strange and scary land for those not used to it. With that said, if I might back this up and talk strategy instead of tactics, I think it's a bad idea to have a modified date in one table to be set by changes in a different table. Ideally each modified date should reflect the last time the row in question was modified, because you'll need that to trouble shoot and follow the chain of custody.

My first alternate suggestion would be a view of the users table with some case logic to determine which modified date would show. You will need to add lastModifiedDate to roles and preferably user_roles, but those aren't hard to setup.

```
Create View UserDetailUpdates
as
select User_Id
  , User_name
  , Name
  , case when max(ud.lastModifiedDate) > max(ro.lastModifiedDate)
    then max(ud.lastModifiedDate) 
    else max(ro.lastModifiedDate) end as lastModifiedDate
  , case when max(ud.lastModifiedDate) > max(ro.lastModifiedDate)
    then 'User Updated' 
    else 'Role Updated' end as ModificationType
From dbo.userDetails ud
  join dbo.User_Role ur on ur.user_id = ud.user_id
  join dbo Role Ro on ro.roleid = ur.roleid
Group by User_Id
  , User_name
  , Name
```

You then just query the view like it's a table, and that should cover it. However if you are really focused on the idea of using a single update date, I can edit that into the answer, and fortunately it won't require a cursor.

Comment: yes, if you can help on single update date then that would be helpful.
As whenever any operations happen on role table then I have to update that lastModofiedDate of user_details table.
I think trigger we have to use right?